# ImageButtons/ImageViews and graphics resized themselves on my app

Tags: android, image, imagebutton, autoresize

I compiled my application, and then reran it, and all of a sudden my graphics have all resized to much smaller versions of themselves...be it ImageViews, ImageButtons, etc...

I did place a small icon in ldpi, a medium one in mdpi and a high one in hdpi - could that be what triggered the issue?  I didn't change my code, so all of my ImageViews I am using as titles for layouts are still set to wrap_content, everything just got smaller.

Any idea why this may be, or are there workarounds?

I test on a Motorola Droid 2, btw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you were just working in `res/drawable` android automatically does the scaling of the asset.

When you added the new assets did you put your existing asset in `res/drawable-mdpi` and then one that is 150% size in `res/drawable-hdpi` and one that is 75% in `res/drawable-ldpi`?

Or did you put your existing asset in `res/drawable-hdpi` and then two smaller versions in `res/drawable-mdpi` and `res/drawable-ldpi`? If you did then your graphics would have appeared to shrink.